# 5 ferries, their capacities and ticket price

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

Five ferries - King's Way, Speedster, Sea Monster, Astar and Blue Surfer operate to Manuchan Island. The capacities of these ferries are 25, 30, 40, 50 and 60, not necessarily in the same order. Each ferry charges a different amount for the ticket per head among Rs. 500, Rs. 300, Rs. 600, Rs. 250 and Rs. 700, not necessarily in the same order. Also, each ferry is completely full when it makes the trip.

> 1. The capacity of Sea Monster is not 25 and the total revenue earned by Astar is not Rs.15000.
> 2. The revenue earned by King's Way is greater than the revenue earned by Blue Surfer.
> 3. The difference between the cost of the tickets of Speedster and Blue Surfer is Rs. 200
> 4. No ferry earns a revenue less than or equal to Rs. 10000.
> 5. The ticket cost of Sea Monster is Rs. 700 and the revenue earned by Astar is not the least.
> 6. The revenue earned by Speedster is greater than Astar.
> 7. No two ferries earn the same revenue.

Map the ferries with their capacities and their revenue, such that all the given conditions are satisfied

(Puzzle Source: IMSindia.com)

Comment: Could you make clear what the question is? Also please cite the source of the puzzle

Comment: We need to map ferries with their capacities and their revenue such that all the given conditions are satisfied

Comment: I solved a similar problem during an aptitude test. Will attempt to solve this one when I have time. In the meantime, please give credit to the source and creator of the puzzle.

Comment: I have added the source of this puzzle. Thanks for pointing it out. I am new to this forum so I will take care about it in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So let’s see:

> The ticket cost of Sea Monster is 700, but they don’t have 25. That gives us the first clue: 25 must be with either 600 or 500 then so that each boat can earn more than 10000. 
>  
>  Further, there is only one pair of costs that are 200 apart: 300 and 500. This means that Speedster and Blue Surfer must have one each, leaving Astar and King’s Way are left with 250 and 600. King’s Way seems to earn a significant amount of money (earning more than another craft), and Astar seems to be near the bottom (but not exactly there). Let’s assume Astar has the 250 cost. 
>  
> !Since total revenue is not 15000, they must not have 60 passengers. But they need more than 40 to be above the 10k limit. So Astar has a 250 cost, 50 passengers, and 12500 revenue. Speedster can’t be at the bottom, neither is King’s Way or Astar; and minimum revenue earned by Sea Monster is 25 x 700 = 17500, so Blue Surfer must have minimum revenue. If their cost was 500, then minimum revenue would be 500 x 25 = 12500, equal to Astar. This is impossible, so they must have cost of 300, and 40 passengers for 12000 revenue (30 passengers leaves them at 9k, short of the 10k minimum). 
>  Speedster then has the 500 cost. They can’t have 50 or 40 or 25 passengers. King’s Way has the 600 cost, and Sea Monster has 700. Sea Monster cannot be 25 either, so King’s Way must have 25 passengers and 600 cost for 15000 revenue. Speedster can’t have the 30 people because 500 x 30 = 15000, so it must have 60 people, total revenue 30000. Then Sea Monster is 30. Then revenue is 21000.

Solution:

> Speedster: 500 x 60 = 30000 
>  Sea Monster: 700 x 30 = 21000 
>  King’s Way: 600 x 25 = 15000 
>  Astar: 250 x 50 = 12500 
>  Blue Surfer: 300 x 40 = 12000

Comment: My bad, i made a formatting edit unaware that you were still trying to modify the content (thought you were just adding extra solutions to the end). Hope i didn't butcher it too much!

Comment: @votbear no worries! I’m done now, hopefully it’s more legible but feel free to go for broke!

Comment: @sam Please consider accepting the answer if it is what you are looking for, so that the community knows it has been resolved! My pleasure. :)